# Can't access variable outside the function scope in JS

Tags: javascript, scope

Sorry for this noobie question, but I've been searching all the existing answer about **shadowing variable**, but still can't make my code work

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        generateInvoice: function() {
             var amount1; // declare a variable
             var amount2;
            this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
                amount1 = 100; //assign value to the amount variable
            });
            this.store.find('product', 2).then(function(obj){
                amount2 = 200; 
            });
            console.log(amount1); // undefined!
            console.log(amount2); // undefined!

            $.post('http://nzud.co.nz/invoice',{
                    foo1: amount1, //access variable amount ---doesn't work!!
                    foo2: amount2

                    } ).done(function(data){
                        alert("success!");
            })
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried a lot of way, but still can't store the model record property into a variable and access from the `$.post` payload

Comment: `this.store.find` is asynchronous

Comment: @adeneo thanks for pointing it out. I need to learn more about promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To proceed using the variable new value, you have to put your code inside the promisse `then`. Then it will work:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        generateInvoice: function() {
            this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
                var amount = 100; //assign value to the amount variable

                $.post('http://nzud.co.nz/invoice',{
                    foo: amount
                }).done(function(data){
                    alert("success!");
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This happens because the method `find` is async, so you have to work with its result inside a callback function, in this case the function `then`. Everything inside `generateInvoice` scope will (probably) be called before your `find` method request ends, even if its the first method called inside it.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't get what you mean with those two `find` methods for `product, 1`, but:

- If you have two values in the request to send to the post, you should use the `find()` method only once:

  ```
  this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
      var amount = 100; //assign value to the amount variable

      $.post('http://nzud.co.nz/invoice',{
          foo: amount,
          bar: another_value
      })
  });
  ```
- Or if you have to call two differents `find` methods, you have to chain them:

  ```
  this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
      var amount = 100; //assign value to the amount variable

      this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
          var another_amount = 100; //assign value to the amount variable

          $.post('http://nzud.co.nz/invoice',{
              foo: amount,
              bar: another_amount
          })
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I just update my question, there are actually two record query promise, so I can't put the `$.post` into one of these

Comment: @mko You have to post both values once in the post request?

Comment: Yes, the payload in the $.post contains two value from two asyc record query

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the second is `store.find('product',2)`

Comment: @mko In this case, yes. You have no another way to do it. So you start a new request after another finishes and so on...

Comment: thank you it works! Later I'll dig deeper into the promise and async programming

Comment: @mko nice. Good luck on it.

Answer (score -1):

Declare amount outside of your function:

```
var amount; // declare a variable
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        generateInvoice: function() {
            this.store.find('product', 1).then(function(obj){
                amount = 100; //assign value to the amount variable
            });
            console.log(amount) // undefined!

            $.post('http://nzud.co.nz/invoice',{
                    foo: amount, //access variable amount ---doesn't work!!

                    } ).done(function(data){
                        alert("success!");
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This maybe call the post function with the `amount` undefined.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, but yeah I missed the part of this being async. Amount still doesn't have a value by the time the post function is ran.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean.